# Clear screen for MYSQL command line client

Tags: windows, command-line, mysql

I am unable to clear the screen of the mysql command line client
like I know in case of java it is 'cls'.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl+l</kbd>?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514914/how-do-i-clear-the-mysql-screen-opened-through-the-mysql-command-line-client

Comment: @Marcell - odd how that works... Perhaps the duplicated you cited should be migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User, too.

Answer (score 2):

In Unix or Linux you can use the:

```
system clear
```

Also you may try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in linux

However if you are using Windows then I think it is not possible. You may refer to this **[bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680)** which is reported for the same for windows.

The only best think I can think of is you can only Exit MySql, Type `CLS` and then re-enter MySql.

Comment: @Supriyo:- You are using windows or linux?

Comment: :-no, it's on windows

Comment: @Supriyo:- Then I dont think it is possible. I have just updated my answer with the bug which is reported for the same

Comment: Then there is no way to clear it? @rahul

Comment: @Supriyo:- In windows there is no way. But I have added an alternative in my answer. But that is just a work around. But it cant be done in windows for sure. This is a bug which has been reported to MYSQL team. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of solutions in Linux like [this one](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/192466), but the consensus seems to be there is none for Windows. See e.g. [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,140151,140151#msg-140151) or [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_21769823.html) (scroll to the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Try `\! cls`; worked for me on Win 10, MySQL Command Line Client 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Unix client?  Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.  Might even work on Windows too ...